# Windows 7 isn't supported post Blender 3.0-3.6: what version of "Windows Server" is supported?

Tags: python, windows

Blender stopped supporting Windows 7, since I think, at Blender 3.0? Or beyond 2.9 is what I think.

I want to use Blender in the future, but not ready to build a Windows 10 machine, but I do want to build a server.

What **Windows Server** will **Blender support**?

From what I read, the Blender 3.0 and above, was due to a very desirable **Python** update. That says a lot. It says that Python is taking over. And it's sad, because Python will follow Windows.

I'd like to build a super machine, RAID, Windows Server, will Blender support it? I am already seeing:

> "Blender 2.79 now working in Windows Server 2019..."

Comments in the forum, like this, popping up.

My main theme is, **Will Blender be supported on Windows Server OS's?** It's a shame if Blender is following only Python-standards-tied-to-Windows advancement. That seems like incentive.

Comment: I am running Blender 3.4 on Windows 7. I made a tutorial video where you can use any version up to Blender 3.4 on windows 7 but try it at your own risk https://youtu.be/n3RGmnRTig8?si=SNvBHdqVehLVVlIq

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to running Windows Server, there is a non official custom compiled version of Blender that supports running modern 3.# versions on older versions of Microsoft operating system like Windows 7.

At the time of writing it currently stands at 3.6.5, and there seem to be instructions on how to build Blender with Windows 7 as target yourself.

https://github.com/nalexandru/BlenderCompat

It has also been packaged as a Portable App at https://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/blendercompat-portable

Alternatively run some form of Linux.

Comment: First of all check "System Requirements for Blender" https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/
Are you running Blender on Windows Server via Remote Desktop Connection?

Comment: I read over the instructions for this build. I'm not excited about using a custom build for projects. The "Blender Compat" is very command line verbose.  Things like "make update" and "git apply" never work for me because I'm not a Unix/Linux guy. And my machine never has all the "Linux" support files that all the Real Linux people have because they use cmd 24/7.

Comment: @SergeyZaykov did you mean to ask me a question on my posted question?

Comment: @ejbytes I have Blender 3 on Windows 8.1.  It works good but doesn't work via Remote Desktop Connection (RDC). As I see the reason is low OpenGL version via RDC.